# jasmine-reporters is not generating any file

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node

i'm using jasmine-reporters to generate a report after protractor finish the tests,

this is my configuration file:

```
  onPrepare: function(){
            var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
            var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
            capsPromise.then(function(caps){
                var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
                var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
                var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
                jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter("protractor_output", true, true,prePendStr));
            });
     },
```

i don't get any error, the reporters installed, but i don't see any file in **protractor_output** folder.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('reports', true, true, prePendStr); instead of the jasmineReporters ?

Comment: yes, i get : TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: that is strange, because you call it a little earlier jasmine.getEnv(). When I started using this reporter for me it also did not write files and when I investigated the junitXmlReporter in mij node_modules dir I found out it did not have the parameters that I expected it to have from other peoples postings on stackoverflow. Maybe that also causes a unlogged error in your setup.

Comment: @AndrePaap it just mean that jasmine those not contain JUnitXmlReporter for some reason, i tried to re-install it and it didn't work, i don't get an error if i use jasmineReporters but i don't see the file in the folder i tried both success and fail and there is no file generated

Comment: maybe I misunderstood. This is my setup:   require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('reports', true, true));. So I create JunitXmlReporter from the global jasmine, but with less paramaters. The jasmine-reports version I use can take the fourth paramaters.

Comment: tried your solution and it didn't work, what version of jasmine are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59046/discussion-between-andre-paap-and-liad-livnat).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The problem is with the jamsine version:**

If you are trying to use jasmine-reporters with Protractor, keep in mind that Protractor is built around Jasmine 1.x. As such, you need to use a 1.x version of jasmine-reporters.

```
npm install jasmine-reporters@~1.0.0
```

then the configuration should be:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters@1.0
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
    );
}
```

If you are on a newer version of the Jasmine Reporter, then the `require` statement no longer puts the `JUnitXmlReporter` on the `jasmine` object, but does put it on the module export.  Your setup would then look like this:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters@1.0
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
    );
}
```

**also you need to verify that xmloutput directory exist!**

Comment: The newer versions of jasmine reporters no longer attaches to the Jasmine object, so you have to use the export.
`var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
...
new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
...`

Comment: @Snekse you should've added that as an answer and it should've been the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer, if the output is still not generating,

Try adding these configuration line to your protractor exports.config object :

```
framework: "jasmine2",
onPrepare: function() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
.......
}
```