# Protractor tests reports using jasmine-reporters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to export protractor test results to xml files, for that I have installed jasmine-reporters using

`npm install -g jasmine-reporters`.

Protractor version is `Version 2.1.0`.

jasmine-reporters version `2.0.7`

This is my protracotr config file:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4455/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  specs: [
    'student_spec.js'
    ],  

  onPrepare: function() {      
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter(null, true, true, '/test/e2e/JasmineReporter')
    );
  },
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000
      }      
};
```

When I run the protractor, I am getting this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-reporters'
```

Help me, where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try installing `jasmine-reporters` without `-g` flag.

Comment: Still getting this error:    Error: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have installed jasmine-reporters and the proper path of jasmine-reporters is provided. If it was installed properly then run the below command to see if you get the version of it -

```
npm list -g jasmine-reporters
```

If there was a problem installing it, use below command to install it which is compatible with Jasmine 2.x versions -

```
npm install --save-dev jasmine-reporters@^2.0.0
```

Update your conf.js file to include proper global scope variable jasmineReporters as mentioned in the package file -

```
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    onPrepare: function() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('path_of_installed_jasmine-reporters-plugin');
    //update proper path, in my case its ('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-reporters')
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter(null, true, true, '/test/e2e/JasmineReporter')
    );};
```

Comment: If I run first command I am getting version like this  -         /usr/local/lib
    └── jasmine-reporters@2.0.7

Comment: Right, then change the global scope variable to **jasmineReporters** instead of what you are using and run the test case again as mentioned above.

Comment: Error: jasmineReporters is not defined

Comment: Updated the answer to change your conf.js file and check if it works. Include framework function and declare jasmineReporters. Hope it works.

Comment: I have updated your change but still getting    
 
**Error: jasmineReporters is not defined**

Comment: Got an answer for your issue. Its because you are not specifying the path to the **jasmine-reporters** when you require it. Inside your **require()** function provide the complete path to the plugin. Updated the same in the answer above. Sorry for the confusion created.

Comment: When using jasmine 2.2.1, I got the error ```JUnitXmlReporter is not a constructor``` when using the code above. I had to use the second version of the code found on the accepted answer on [this stackoverflow accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228472/jasmine-reporters-is-not-generating-any-file) to get around the error message: ```var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
    );```.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters').jasmineReporters;
```

?
I think something like that should work.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue as I installed jasmine locally.But when I installed jasmine as Globally it works fine for me.

```
npm install –g jasmine-reporters@^2.0.0
```

then,

```
npm list -g jasmine-reporters
```

After that run the conf.js again as mentioned above